# @Indexed annotation ignored when using named collections

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a pojo annotated like this:

```
@Document
class Car {

  @Id
  String id ;

  @Indexed
  String manufacturer ;

}
```

And I am using `MongoTemplate` to insert into mongo. If I insert without specifying a collection name, everything works fine. However, if I specify a collection name, none of the indexes are created except for the `_id` one.

I really need to be able to specify the collection name manually because:

- I need to ensure different subclasses of `Car` end up in the same collection
- I would like to store each year's worth of `Cars` in a separate collection

Do I have to call `ensureIndex()` myself manually? If so, is there a way to do it that uses my `@Indexed` annotations? The actual objects I am trying to save are a lot more complex than 'Car'

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23942469/create-index-in-correct-collection

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately `MongoTemplate` function

```
public void insert(Object objectToSave, String collectionName)
```

using `collectionName` only for saving object and not for creating any annotated indexes.
If object passed to save operation then application event listener `MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator` scan saved entity class for `@Indexed` annotations and create indexes. But it detect collection name based on next formula (from sources):

```
String collection = StringUtils.hasText(index.collection()) ? index.collection() : entity.getCollection();
```

where `index.collection()` is collection from `@Indexed` annotation and `entity.getCollection()` from `@Document` annotation.

So, you need to call `ensureIndex()` manually.
It's strange behaviour. I think you can open bug here: [DATAMONGO](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAMONGO)

**EDIT:** 
I think you can create function that return all classes annotated with `@Document` and  also get all collections from mongodb started from `cars.<year>`. Then you can analyse all fields annotated with `@Indexed` and, as result, call `ensureIndex` for this fields using collections list.

Comment: @Dave: see may addition to answer

Answer (score 2):

> I really need to be able to specify the collection name manually because:

```
I need to ensure different subclasses of Car end up in the same collection
I would like to store each year's worth of Cars in a separate collection
```

As for your first statement, you can enforce a single collection using `@Document` metadata annotation:

```
@Document(collection="cars")
class Car {

    @Id
    String id ;

    @Indexed
    String manufacturer ;

}

@Document(collection="cars")
class Honda extends Car {

}

@Document(collection="cars")
class Volvo extends Car {

}
```

The collection field of `@Document` will take care that every subclass of car gets into the cars collection,  plus the index is automatically created with the help of the `@Indexed` annotation.

Comment: That would be fine except, as you say, it doesn't help me with the second point =(

Comment: I didn't understand your second point. Please give an example

Comment: Sure thing. Not sure how widespread this use-case is, but for me it makes a lot of sense to maintain completely separate collections for each client of mine. The actual object I am storing is a tweet (not a car), and for each client I might gather hundreds of thousands of tweets. For each tweet I'll attach different annotations for each client. So, if they are all in one collection, it can get huge, and I have to add lots of extra fields to keep track of which client cared about the tweet and the annotations on it. One collection=messy, multiple collections=clean.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe better off stooping to the DB level and checking if the collection has indexes you need using [getIndexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getIndexes/#db.collection.getIndexes) and calling the ensureIndex as part of your application start up.

Tip: Implement InitializingBean on the class that configures mongo for your application and do the magic there.

No preaching, IMHO Spring is good at certain things and so-so at others. I try to avoid the bloat other than for DI & TXN management in non XA environments.

Answer (score 0):

After a long search, I think that for now is not posible using annotations, so I created a programmatically way to manage this scenario.

creating normal index and compound index

First I defined an object to map the index structure.

```
public class CollectionDefinition {

private String id;
private String collectionName;
private LinkedHashMap<String, Sort.Direction> normalIndexMap;
private ArrayList<String> compoundIndexMap;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCollectionName() {
    return collectionName;
}

public void setCollectionName(String collectionName) {
    this.collectionName = collectionName;
}

public LinkedHashMap<String, Sort.Direction> getNormalIndexMap() {
    return normalIndexMap;
}

public void setNormalIndexMap(LinkedHashMap<String, Sort.Direction> normalIndexMap) {
    this.normalIndexMap = normalIndexMap;
}

public ArrayList<String> getCompoundIndexMap() {
    return compoundIndexMap;
}

public void setCompoundIndexMap(ArrayList<String> compoundIndexMap) {
    this.compoundIndexMap = compoundIndexMap;
}
```

The Json collection will look like this

```
{
"collectionName" : "example", 
"normalIndexMap" : {
    "sessionId" : "ASC", 
    "hash" : "DESC"
}, 
"compoundIndexMap" : [
    "{\"hash\":1,\"sessionId\":1,\"serverDate\":-1}", 
    "{\"sessionId\":1,\"serverDate\":-1}", 
    "{\"sessionId\":1,\"loginWasSuccessful\":1,\"loginDate\":-1}"
]}
```

Then We can create the collection and the indexes

```
private List<IndexDefinition> createIndexList(Map<String, Sort.Direction> normalIndexMap) {
    Set<String> keySet = normalIndexMap.keySet();
    List<IndexDefinition> indexArray = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String key : keySet) {
        indexArray.add(new Index(key, normalIndexMap.get(key)).background());
    }
    return indexArray;
}
```

The resulting single index list can be used to create single field index

```
private void createIndexes(List<IndexDefinition> indexDefinitionList, MongoOperations mongoOperations, String collectionName) {
    indexDefinitionList.forEach(indexDefinition -> mongoOperations.indexOps(collectionName).ensureIndex(indexDefinition));
}
```

The compound index or multifield index is tricky, We need to create DBObjects to define the index

```
private List<DBObject> createCompountIndexList(List<String> compoundIndexStringMapList) {//NOSONAR IS IN USE
    if (compoundIndexStringMapList == null || compoundIndexStringMapList.isEmpty())
        return new ArrayList<>(); //NOSONAR
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<DBObject> basicDBObjectList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String stringMapList : compoundIndexStringMapList) {
        LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> parsedMap;
        try {
            parsedMap = mapper.readValue(stringMapList, new TypeReference<Map<String, Integer>>() {
            });
            BasicDBObjectBuilder dbObjectBuilder = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start();
            Iterator it = parsedMap.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry indexElement = (Map.Entry) it.next();
                dbObjectBuilder.add((String) indexElement.getKey(), indexElement.getValue());
                it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
            }
            basicDBObjectList.add(dbObjectBuilder.get());
        } catch (IOException e) {//NOSONAR I´m logging it, we can not do anything more here cause it is part of the db configuration settings that need to be correct
            Logger.getLogger(JsonCollectionCreation.class).error("The compound index definition " + stringMapList + " is not correct it can not be mapped to LinkHashMap");
        }

    }
    return basicDBObjectList;
}
```

And the result can be used to create the index in the collection

```
private void createCompoundIndex(List<DBObject> compoundIndexList, MongoOperations mongoOperations, String collectionName) {
    if (compoundIndexList.isEmpty()) return;
    for (DBObject compoundIndexDefinition : compoundIndexList) {
        mongoOperations.indexOps(collectionName).ensureIndex(new CompoundIndexDefinition(compoundIndexDefinition).background());
    }
}
```